# __isoc99_scanf and scanf

Tags: c, iso

I was studying various compiler option in GCC and observing changes when I made changes in the standard to be used.

```
$ gcc Q1.c -Wall -save-temps -o Q1
$ vi Q1.s
```

I see one of the opcodes as

```
 call    __isoc99_scanf
```

and now when I compile with the C89 standards

```
$gcc Q1.c -Wall -save-temps -std=c89 -o Q1
$ vi Q1.s
```

I see the opcode as

```
call    scanf
```

What is the difference between these two forms of `scanf`? Any link where I can see their source would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is strict following of c99 disallow some existing GNU extension conversion specifiers.

In glibc 2.17, in `libio/stdio.h` there is this comment:

```
/* For strict ISO C99 or POSIX compliance disallow %as, %aS and %a[
   GNU extension which conflicts with valid %a followed by letter
   s, S or [.  */
extern int __REDIRECT (fscanf, (FILE *__restrict __stream,
    const char *__restrict __format, ...),
    __isoc99_fscanf) __wur;
extern int __REDIRECT (scanf, (const char *__restrict __format, ...),
    __isoc99_scanf) __wur;
extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (sscanf, (const char *__restrict __s,
      const char *__restrict __format, ...),
      __isoc99_sscanf);
```

Answer (score 6):

[scanf(3) manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) mentions several type modifiers characters introduced in c99:

```
j      As for h, but the next pointer is a pointer to an intmax_t or a uintmax_t.  This modifier was introduced in C99
t      As for h, but the next pointer is a pointer to a ptrdiff_t.  This modifier was introduced in C99.
z      As for h, but the next pointer is a pointer to a size_t.  This modifier was introduced in C99.
a      (C99) Equivalent to f
```