# Why gcc need -D_GNU_SOURCE

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

When I make a gcc compile command with the option "-L",I should add the gblic library path or add -D_GNU_SOURCE or the gcc will run error.

```
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/ -lc
$/tmp/ccq1Z6T1.o：function ‘main’：
  sscanf_test.c:(.text+0x32)：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
  sscanf_test.c:(.text+0xf8)：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
  sscanf_test.c:(.text+0x1e4)：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
  collect2: ld return 1
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/ -D_GNU_SOURCE
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/ /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Now, I have puzzle that why gcc need  -D_GNU_SOURCE.Another machine have a similar environment can run normally without -D_GNU_SOURCE.

Comment: what is `gblic`? Did you mean `glibc`?

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16376341/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I mean  the superset of all 
other standards under GNU C libraries.

Comment: Why this C++1 tag? What does this have to do with C++ ?

Comment: @JensGustedt em,isn't gcc similar to c++?

Comment: @hrl, gcc is a compiler C++ is a programming language. How can one be another? gcc is a compiler for many languages, C and C++ among them.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for your  recommendation.It may related to my question ,but I don't understand its  conclusion and can't get a solution from it.

Comment: @JensGustedt I am sorry for that. I will add gcc tag and remove the c++ tag,thanks.But as you know ,gcc is a compiler for many languages , I just think someone who is good at c++ may also know more about gcc complier and help me to find the answer .So that I add the c++ tag.

Comment: "So that I add the c++ tag." This is called "tag spamming" and it's considered as bad behavior.

Comment: @Scheff I'm sorry about that. I'll pay attention next time

Answer (score -1):

You need `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in-order to use GNU extension features/functions. You can use low level functions such as `socket`, `ifconfig`, etc.

> Macro: _GNU_SOURCE If you define this macro, everything is included:
> ISO C89, ISO C99, POSIX.1, POSIX.2, BSD, SVID, X/Open, LFS, and GNU
> extensions. In the cases where POSIX.1 conflicts with BSD, the POSIX
> definitions take precedence.

Compiling without `-D_GNU_SOURCE` may run on one Linux machine without any problem but then fail on other Linux variants if they use a different C standard library.

---

**Very straight forward answer:**

- `#define _GNU_SOURCE 1` enables GNU extensions supported by the GNU C library. Define it when you're using non-standard functions and macros.  In your case, you're trying to use a non-standard function that is part of POSIX, that's why you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE 1`.
- You want to get the full effect of `_GNU_SOURCE` but make the BSD
  definitions take precedence over the POSIX definitions, the use the `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Check this answer for more info about defining [_GNU_SOURCE.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583764/7640269)

Comment: This is so wrong. First of all, it's `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, not `-DGNU_SOURCE` or `-GNU_SOURCE`. Second of all, header files are located in `/usr/include`, not `/usr/lib`.