# Not able to use function from my dynamic library loaded via LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-library, ld-preload

I am trying to use `sscanf()` from *preload.so* which is generated from *preload.c*.

To check my `sscanf()` from *preload.so* is called, I added extra print statement: `printf("test\n");`

Is there something I am missing?

Files content mentioned below:

```
//preload.c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  printf("test\n");
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
```

```
//foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i;
        sscanf("42", "%d", &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```

I am doing below steps:

```
# gcc -fPIC -shared preload.c -o preload.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
# export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload.so
# gcc foo.c -o foo
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

O/p I am getting:

```
# echo $LD_PRELOAD
/AMIT/sscanf_override/preload.so
# ./foo
42
# LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload.so ./foo
42
```

The expected output is:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload.so ./foo
test
42
```

Even ldd output is pointing to *preload.so* as below, still while execution its giving preference to `sscanf()` of system and not the one from *preload.so*

```
root@***sscanf_override]# ldd foo
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff4a5e0000)
        /AMIT/sscanf_override/preload.so (0x00007f1cf270a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1cf2345000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1cf2141000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1cf290c000)
[root@***sscanf_override]#
```

Tweak here is, if I remove `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1`,it works, `gcc -fPIC -shared preload.c -o preload.so -ldl` But I can not proceed ahead without defining GNU_SOURCE as its must for future use .

As suggested by @Rachid K, it worked when I redefined my preload.c as below:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  printf("test\n");
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}

__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int __isoc99_sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  printf("test\n");
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sscanf()` may be a macro referencing an internal function. Have a look at *<stdio.h>*. For example, on my system, I have:

```
extern int __isoc99_sscanf (const char *__restrict __s,
                            const char *__restrict __format, ...) __THROW;
#  define fscanf __isoc99_fscanf
#  define scanf __isoc99_scanf
#  define sscanf __isoc99_sscanf
```

Hence, `sscanf()` is actually a macro referencing `__isoc99_sscanf()`. So, if you redefine the latter, you get what you expect.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
int __isoc99_sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  printf("test\n");
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
```

After rebuild, you get:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared preload.c -o preload.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
$ LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/preload.so ./foo
test
42
```

Comment: K, let me try this, but Tweak here is , if I remove -D_GNU_SOURCE=1,it works, gcc -fPIC -shared preload.c -o preload.so -ldl But I can not proceed ahead without defining GNU_SOURCE as its must

Comment: Rachid K : Great it worked. 
I edited my question with solution which I tried as per your suggestion.

Comment: K : Any suggestion on my post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459449/can-i-do-nested-calls-for-system-functions-loaded-by-ld-preload)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `readelf -s foo`.

I think it is likely that there is no call to `sscanf` in your executable. Assuming you are using GLIBC as libc, I suspect a call to `__isoc99_sscanf`. This is a redirection which the library makes, apparently because its original `sscanf` variant uses extensions conflicting with the standard, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376341/isoc99-scanf-and-scanf).

If you look then at `readelf -s preload.so` as well, it will probably show a definition for `sscanf`.

The redirection happens via macro in `stdio.h` which you include in both, but I suspect `_GNU_SOURCE=1` disables the redirection, so that even though `stdio.h` is included in `preload.c`, it is not replacing `sscanf` with `__isoc99_sscanf` there.

In the compilation of `foo`, you probably do not use `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1` and therefore you are getting a mismatch between the symbol names.

Symbol interposition with `LD_PRELOAD` is always a bit tricky. In addition to issues such as above, there are also many situations in which compilers will optimize out or transform standard library calls. For example `printf` -> `puts` if the format string doesn't use any formatting.

Comment: Tweak here is , if I remove -D_GNU_SOURCE=1,it works,
 gcc -fPIC -shared preload.c -o preload.so -ldl
But I can not proceed ahead without defining  GNU_SOURCE as its must.

Comment: @AmitMendhe I think `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1` switches back to the original `sscanf` implementation with the extensions. You probably only see a problem if you mismatch that flag between compilation of the executable and the `preload.so`, since the redirection happens via macro in `stdio.h`, which you are including in both.

Comment: Thanks @user17732522.
 : Any suggestion on my post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459449/can-i-do-nested-calls-for-system-functions-loaded-by-ld-preload)