# can I do nested calls for system functions loaded by LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, scanf, localtime, ld-preload

Hi I am trying to override `sscanf()` which gets called from `localtime()`,
But its not calling `sscanf()` of my library loaded rather its calling `sscanf()` of glibc.

Is there something I am missing?

Files content mentioned below:

```
//preload_localtime.c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  printf("test\n");
  va_start(ap, format);
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}

__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) int __isoc99_sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  printf("test\n");
  va_start(ap, format);
  ret = vsscanf(str, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) struct tm *
localtime(const time_t *timep)
{
    static struct tm *(*real_localtime)(const time_t *) = (void*)0;

    printf("my_local\n");
   if (!real_localtime)
        real_localtime = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "localtime");
    return real_localtime(timep);
}


//foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)
{
        int i;
        //sscanf("42", "%d", &i);
        //printf("%d\n", i);

time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
 timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
        return 0;
}
```

Steps I am doing:

```
# gcc -fPIC -shared preload_localtime.c -o preload_localtime.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
#export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload_localtime.so
gcc foo.c -o foo
```

output I am getting:

```
# ./foo
my_local
Current local time and date: Wed Mar 10 18:20:47 2021
```

What is expected output:
It should print `test` as well, from   `printf("test\n");` of `sscanf()` overriden.
Since `localtime()` internally has call to `sscanf()` and I have overridden and instructed to use `sscanf()` as well.

IS there any way to override another system call like in this example `sscanf()` which is internally gets called from `localtime()`.

Call hierarchy as below:

```
localtime()->__tz_convert() ->__tzfile_compute() -->__tzset_parse_tz() -->parse_offset() -->sscanf()
```

Comment: Are you sure that localtime() calls sscanf() ? In my glibc, it calls an internal __tz_convert().

Comment: @RachidK. Yes its call traces is as below:
```
#0  0x00007ffff6e7740e in __GI__IO_vfscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#1  0x00007ffff6e8b401 in vsscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6e859d8 in sscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6ed0bce in parse_offset () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6ed115a in __tzset_parse_tz () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff6ed2c50 in __tzfile_compute () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff6ed16f9 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7                                      localtime()
```

Comment: __tz_convert ->__tzfile_compute -->__tzset_parse_tz -->parse_offset -->sscanf

Answer (score 2):

`LD_PRELOAD` works by being the first symbol of the same name found by the dynamic linker - so if a symbol usage can be resolved in compile time, the dynamic linking won't affect it
because `localtime` and `sscanf` exist in the same binary the call may very well be a static one - the call can be resolved in compile time and the dynamic linker isn't involved in this call chain.

Comment: Yes you are right otherwise this would mean that the glibc needs the glibc to work.